# How to add a CRLF in a Textarea in IE6 with Coldfusion?

Tags: html, coldfusion, internet-explorer-6, coldfusion-7

How can I add a CRLF into a Textarea using Coldfusion 7 code?

I've tried every way that I can think of and every way that I've found. Nothing is working for IE6. In Chrome and IE8 pretty much everything I try works fine... However, this app has to run in IE6.

The below code is how I'm building my string for the textarea.

```
<cfset qResults = "">
<cfif myQuery.RecordCount GT 0>
    <cfloop query="myQuery">
        <cfset qResults="#qResults#" 
                          & "#qfield1# #qfield2# #qfield3# &nbsp;|__|&nbsp; " 
                          & Chr(13) & Chr(10)>
    </cfloop>
<cfelse>
```

As you can see, I've just gone to separating the different query returns by an ugly |__| since I can't get anything else to work.

I've also tried just the CR or just the LF and I've also tried html breaks.

---

@Dan Roberts

Well, that could be the issue. This is pulling data in dynamically through javascript. The user clicks a textbox, selects from a dropdown, and the rest of the fields on the form are populated with the relevant information. The code above, actually sits on a popDB.cfm page, it's called by

```
$.post("popDB.cfm", {id: thisValue}, function(data) {
        var dataArr = data.split(',');
```

Later on in the function, the actual field is populated by:

```
$('#qResultsID' + iter).html(dataArr[16]);
```

**I have tried all these methods separately as well.**

Comment: Are you outputing qResults in each pass of the loop? There is no issue with using chr(10) in textareas in my experience. Your code however will not produce a string with multiple records to be output.

Comment: No, I am building a string and my string works fine. The CRLF in IE6 is the issue.

Comment: Have you tried inverting them? (`Chr(10) & Chr(13)`)

Comment: Yes, and I just tried a again to be sure.

Comment: I misread the code... missed the "#qResults#". How are you outputting the string in the textarea? Like I said, have not had issues using chr(10) by itself. Have used for many years.

Comment: I'm with dan ... try "just" chr(10)

Comment: @Dan There was too much to type here, I added in an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

chr(10) should work for you if there are no other issues

```
<cfset str = "" />
<cfloop list="item1,item2,item3" index="listitem">
    <cfset str &= listitem & chr(10) />
</cfloop>
<cfoutput><textarea rows="10" cols="10">#str#</textarea></cfoutput>
```

Comment: Thanks, You didn't solve my issue directly but you got me thinking down the right path to solve it. The solution was to add `<cfset str &= "#str#<br>" & Chr(10)>` I'm not entirely sure why that works, where neither part works independently, but I think it might have something to do with the way it's being passed. Thank you.